# Why use an idp issued id_token -- versus a custom session cookie?

Tags: azure-ad-b2c, openid-connect

I'm struggling to understand when to use a session cookie, or just use the IdP issued token as a bearer token.

Is the primary advantage of using an IdP issued token that you get a *standards* based mechanism for tokens (including ensuring non-tampering, as the JWT is signed)?

As opposed to using a proprietary vendor mechanism of converting it to a claim identity, and then to a custom session cookie (as per owin middleware)?

Doesn't the custom cookie approach have an advantage that one can add non-ipd issued claims (eg: from a system db)?

What *other* key advantage does using an idp issued id_token have over a cookie based session approach?

Is it maybe that a bearer token approach would not need caching on the server, so that one can re-use it to call 3rd party services that have a different audience value? Whereas the token would be lost if we used a cookie? (I'm reaching, I know, as I don't yet understand how calling 3rd party services works).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Id token is meant for your user-facing app as proof of who the user is.
It is then up to your app how you choose to authenticate the user on future requests.

While technically you could just store the Id token and use that, as you mentioned, it cannot be extended since it is digitally signed.
Which for most our projects is no good.

At least in regular Azure AD (not sure about B2C), you cannot use the Id token to get an access token for another API.
In there, you would have to get an *authorization code* in addition to the Id token at the time of sign in,
and exchange that for an access token (which you then cache server-side).

If you use the Id token as an authentication token for your app, keep in mind that Id tokens issued from the token endpoint (when exchanging an authorization code in normal Azure AD) are not signed (I guess since you receive them as a response to your request + over HTTPS).
Only the Id token you get in the redirect back to your app is signed in normal AAD.
I am not sure if this applies to B2C as well.